certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain when running dbt deps
I'm running a dbt test and I need to load the dbt dependencies so that I have access to
- dbt_utils.accepted_range:
min_value: 0
max_value: 100
Here's the package.yml
    packages:
      - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
        version: 1.1.1


In order to leverage the dbt_utils.accepted_range i need to run dbt deps in the project.  But when I do I get the following cert error:

    root@891906d968a0:/usr/app/dbt# dbt deps
    17:17:03  Running with dbt=1.7.14
    17:17:05  Installing dbt-labs/dbt_utils
    17:17:17  Encountered an error:
    External connection exception occurred: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='codeload.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dbt-labs/dbt-utils/tar.gz/1.1.1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)')))


I'm running dbt from a container against an Azure SQL.  Everything worked until I added the package in the packages.yml file.  It's only an issue when trying to test the accepted values range.
I've tried this:
pip install pip_system_certs
I've also tried:
python -m pip install python-certifi-win32
pip install certify
/Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command
